# Session Value Not Being Updated In View

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.6

In my laravel app I have a master blade template and child pages that extend that master blade template.

When a user logs in, in the master blade template I fetch the number of points a user has, store it in a Session variable and display it in the view, this works:

**LoginController.php**

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   $userPoints = UserPoint::where("user_id", $user->id)->first();
   ()->put("availablePoints", $userPoints->points);
   session()->save();
}
```

**master.blade.php:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
   Hi, You have <span id="userPoints">{{ session()->get("availablePoints") }}</span>points
</li>
```

Now my points.blade.php view extends the master.blade.php view, I have a button in this view that allows a user to get new points, in my controller I add to what the user already has and try to update the session to the new value:

```
$userPoints = Point::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->first();
$userPoints->points = ($userPoints->points + 50); 
$userPoints->expires_at = new Carbon('first day of next month');
$userPoints->save();

session()->put("availablePoints", $userPoints->points);
session()->save();
```

Now for some reason even after doing this and reloading the page it still displays the previous value before the update was made.  The session value does not update the new value is only displayed when I logout and log back in again.

**EDIT:**
1. I am using the **file** driver

2. I logged the session value after the update and the new value had been saved however it is not refreshed in the view.
3. The request to get additional points is an AJAX request.

Comment: Try stop doing `session()->save();`.

Comment: I was just doing ```session(["" => ""]);``` before, didn't work

Comment: Put `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file. Storing the session data happens only if controller action finished successfully.

Comment: APP_DEBUG is already set to TRUE

Comment: What session driver you are using?

Comment: The file driver.

Comment: Did you tried `session("availablePoints", $userPoints->points)` ?

Comment: One more things to check. Is your route using "web" middleware?